# Getting Redux Reducer to Merge Arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So what's going on here is I'm trying to setup auto pagination. I setup a while loop that sends get requests while the number of array items in the returned data is greater than 0. Each loop it sends the data over to my reducer AppendUserHistoryReducer as shown in the code below.

What I would like to happen, is for the reducer to append each loop of data it recieves into a single array. As it stands I've only figured out how to store each loop of data in a separate array in state (shown in the console picture). I could map over the data and merge it all together after the fact, but I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this, so writing that additional code isn't necessary. Meaning, can it be done in the reducer?

Just to be clear my goal is for totalUserHistory state to be [0 - 729], instead of broken up into different arrays, just by modifying the code in the reducer.

Code I'm seeking help with:

```
export const AppendUserHistoryReducer = (userData=[], action) => {
  if (action.type === 'APPEND_USER_DATA') {
    return  [...userData.concat(action.payload)] 
  }
  return userData;
}
```

While loop code, just for context:

```
  // auto pagination
  while (this.props.userHistory.length > 0) {
    let { userHistory } = this.props
    let lastPage = userHistory[userHistory.length-1].data.name

    const response = await axios.get (`https://oauth.reddit.com/user/${userIdentityObject.data.name}/saved/.json?limit=100&after=${lastPage}`, {
    headers: { 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}` }
  })
    console.log('a loop');
    this.props.storeUserHistory(response.data.data.children)
    this.props.appendUserHistory(response.data.data.children)
  }
}
```

Produces multiple arrays in the console:

[image]

Comment: Note that `totalHistory` array length is 730 - the console is just breaking them down into smaller groupings. Assuming it's the multiple arrays that are causing issues, this is only an issue you'll see in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot you have a single array with all items. It's just chrome dev tool visually separates the array for debugging convenience.

In order to ensure that there is only a single array, you can stringify it and then print to console:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(totalUserHistory))
```